# How can i add to the List<string> the last file from the directory?

Tags: c#

```
if (Form1.sf != null)
{
    radarDI = new DirectoryInfo(Form1.sf);
    radarFiles = radarDI.GetFiles("*.png");
    for (int i = radarFiles.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        myGifListRadar.Add(radarFiles[i].Name);
    }
}
```

radarFiles contain 224 files. I want to add to the `myGifListRadar List<string>` the last 5 or any last number of files from the end of files on the hard disk.

If im doing for `int I = 0 ; I < test.Length; I++` it will add:

> 00001.png
>
> 00002.png

I want it to add from the end:

> 00224.png
>
> 00223.png

and so on...So I tried to change the FOR to as it is now but im getting exception out of bound :

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

Whats wrong with the FOR ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a zero bound index so its length -1, you also want a greater then or equal to for the count down to zero or you will miss the first element in the array.

```
for (int i = radarFiles.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
}
```

Comment: However, i've understood the question differently. I think OP wants to  order by the file name and get the 5 highest numbers (e.g. 00224.png
,00223.png,...)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
for (int i = radarFiles.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

arrays and other collections start indexing at zero, so you have to subtract 1 from the length

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
for (int i = radarFiles.Length; i > 0; i--)
```

To this:

```
for (int i = radarFiles.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

You were starting past the end of the list.  Also, you need to use >= instead of just > or you will miss a file if the directory is small enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable.OrderByDescending` + `Enumerable.Take`:

```
var last5Files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png")
    .Select(p => new { Path = p, FileName = Path.GetFileName(p) })
    .Select(x => new { x.FileName, Number = x.FileName.TryGetInt() })
    .Where(x => x.Number.HasValue)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Number.Value)
    .Select(x => x.FileName)
    .Take(5);
foreach (string fn in last5Files)
    myGifListRadar.Add(fn);
```

This is the extension method i've used to get a `int?` from your file-name:

```
public static class NumericExtensions
{
    public static int? TryGetInt(this string item)
    {
        int i;
        bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
        return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
    }
}
```

(asuming that you only want png-files that have a numeric filename)

Answer (score 1):

Since your files have name of that format you can use this:

```
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path)
                  .OrderByDescending(n => Path.GetFileName(n))
                  .Take(5)
                  .ToList();
```